# HQL Join Query with InheritanceType.JOINED Based on Subclass' Criteria

Tags: java, hql

Using a NamedQuery, how to fetch a related table that is using `InheritanceType.JOINED` based on a field of the subclass?

I have a setup similar to this:

**Class with the NamedQuery**:

```java
@NamedQuery(<named-query>)
@Entity
@Table(name="T_PERSON")
public class Person {
    private Vehicle vehicle;
}
```

**Abstract Class being referenced by first class:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_VEHICLE")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "vehicleType")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private Long vehicleId;
    private String vehicleType;
}
```

**Concrete subclass of the Abstact Class:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_CAR")
@DiscriminatorValue("CAR")
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    private String make;
}
```

I'm trying to write a `<named-query>` in the `Person` class which will be similar to this SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM T_PERSON person
LEFT JOIN T_VEHICLE vehicle ON vehicle.VEHICLE_ID = person.VEHICLE_ID
LEFT JOIN T_CAR car on car.VEHICLE_ID = vehicle.VEHICLE_ID
WHERE car.MAKE = 'Honda'
```

The issue I'm running into is that the `Person` class only has a reference to the superclass `Vehicle`, and not the subclass `Car`, so trying to write a NamedQuery simliar to this fails:

```sql
Select person from Person person 
left join person.Vehicle vehicle
where vehicle.make = 'Honda'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to query it like this:

```sql
SELECT person FROM Person person 
INNER JOIN person.vehicle vehicle, Car car
WHERE vehicle.vehicleId = car.vehicleId
    AND car.make = 'Honda'
```